# Using categories on navigation bar instead of pages

Tags: css, design

Check this url ([www.linuxstall.com](http://www.linuxstall.com/)). The top navigation bar has one page (about us). I want the categories there, not pages. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the nav menus you can just add specific categories from your administration panel in Apperence->menus. If you don't see the categories box open "screen options" and check them to display.
If you want dinamicly add them you will need to write a plugin.

Comment: I have made the custom menu which includes categories. Now how to add that to TOP BAR WHICH IS HAVING ABOUT US PAGE?

Comment: If you have a nav registered and wp_nav_menu() called in the theme you pick a menu for a specific location in Apperence->Menus->Theme location